# Cannot add an identity that already exists

Tags: linq-to-sql

I'm using C#4.0 in a simple expense recording app.  I'm trying to save to a table with an auto incremented id field, set as the primary key.  It works fine the first time I use it, but the second and subsequent time, I get the "Cannot add an identity that already exists" error.

Here's the code I'm having trouble with

```
public bool SaveClaim(Claim newClaim, bool blNew)
{
    bool blSuccess = true;
    try
    {
        expContext.Claims.InsertOnSubmit(newClaim);
        expContext.SubmitChanges();
        claim = null;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        blSuccess = false;
        MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
    }
    return blSuccess;
}
```

I've been working on this all morning, and it's driving me daft.  I'd be glad for any help.

Comment: I've tried fixing your broken code, but it's still incomplete.  Where is `blNew` being used?  What is `claim = null` for?

Comment: Try running a SQL Query Profiler to find out what is being executed, and verify the id is actually being incremented and not passed in.

Comment: the second time you call it, is that really a new claim or have you changed the existing Claim entity? The latter will not work.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are trying to *UPDATE* newClaim using the *INSERT* method.

If newClaim has an ID and the method `expContext.Claims.InsertOnSubmit(newClaim)` is trying to insert a record with that ID. That could be the issue.

```
if (blNew)
    expContext.Claims.InsertOnSubmit(newClaim);
else
    expContext.Claims.UpdateOnSubmit(newClaim); //-- Assumed method
```

**Additional**

Here is a useful thread: [MSDN Forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/linqtosql/thread/ed02efc8-082f-4139-b9ac-f8bef3dbb1e9)

```
if (blNew)
{
        expContext.Claims.InsertOnSubmit(newClaim);
}
```

Comment: there is no such thing as UpdateOnSubmit on linq2sql. You just alter the entity and do submitchanges.

Comment: True. So with a little more research I have adjusted my answer.

Comment: Thanks very much Guys, your help was invaluable.  I'm new to linqtoSQL and I can see I have a lot to learn.  BTW I was re-using the claim entity, and that's what was causing the trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure you have the following properties set in your dbml for the identity column of Claim:

Auto Generated Value = true

Auto-Sync = OnInsert

Also ensure that your new Claim object is actually a new object, and not a reuse of the one you previously added.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try updating your designer.
Remove the table Claim, update the server explorer, and add it again.

At least that's what I do when I get this error. It usually shows when I set the identity column on the database after compiling.